# How do I airport-utils to configure my Airport Extreme?

Tags: networking, package-management, apple

I'm trying to use this package ([airport-utils](http://packages.ubuntu.com/oneiric/airport-utils)) to try to configure my Airport Extreme. I was able to install it without a problem using `apt-get` but when I try to use it nothing happens. Literally, *nothing*:

```
shreyas@shreyas-laptop:~$ airport2-portinspector 
shreyas@shreyas-laptop:~$
```

No windows open, nothing. I tried calling `ps aux` and grepping for anything that might hint to the command actually doing something but I came up empty.

Does anyone have any experience with this package and can help me, or is there something else I can do to work with my Airport Extreme?

Comment: Hi, have you resolved your issue?

Comment: Nope, still looking for help. Although, I haven't tried anything on Pangolin yet.

Comment: Could you try out and report back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably due to a non-supported java version. I got the same result until I used `gcj-4.4`. Install command:

```
apt-get install gcj-4.4-jre gcj-4.4-jdk fastjar
```

You will then need to use that version of java (i.e. launch with `/usr/lib/jvm/java-gcj-4.4/bin/java` instead of just java by setting `$JAVACMD`.)

Comment: I can confirm that this solution works also on Ubuntu 13.04, but with gcj-4.7-jre. Running "export JAVACMD=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.7-i386/bin/java" before airport-config solves the problem.